# Unable to access kubernetes pods using External IP

Tags: kubernetes, service

I am using imperative way (yaml files not used) to deploy the pod into cluster and expose it using LoadBalancer service to access it.. But unfortunately I am getting connection timeout issue.

My Docker file looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
ADD publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DemoApi.dll"]
```

Note : Publish folder has all the libraries to run the exe..

Then I pushed that into docker hub.

I tried to run the  image using the following two commands..

First created the pod in cluster as below.

```
kubectl run demo-api-pod --image ***/demoapi:2.0.0.2
```

Then tried to expose this pod using the service.

```
kubectl expose pod demo-api-pod --type=Loadbalancer --port=80 --name=demo-api-service
```

On running the "kuebctl get svc", I got the external IP.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnKSF.png)

When I tried ot access **http://20.195.35.174/weatherforecast**, I received connection timeout issue.

I even tried setting the environment variable "ASPNETCORE_URLS" while running the pod.

```
kubectl run demo-api-pod --image ***/demoapi:2.0.0.2 --env="ASPNETCORE_URLS=80"
```

Even exposing the pod that was created as above was not accessible.

what is that I am missing here.. kindly help.

Comment: Where is load balancer being created? Can it be a some sort of firewall? Is environment allowed to accept traffic from HTTP port?

Comment: Load balancer is created inside the cluster. yes the env can accept http traffic.

Comment: Okay can we try this? `kubectl expose pod demo-api-pod --type=Loadbalancer --port=80 --target-port=80 --name=demo-api-service`

Comment: Can you provide more information on your cluster environment. Are you testing locally on your computer, i.e. minikube, kind, Docker K8s, etc. Or are you deploying to Azure, AWS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Oguzhan..
I was able to fix the issue by these two ways.

1. change the docker file base file from

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS base
   ```

to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
```

The reason is, the first sdk doesnt have the "aspnetcore_urls" environment varibale set.

2. if we still wnat to proceed with the SDK image, then we need to add the environent variable manually in hte docker file or we can set it while running the image as below.

   ```
    kubectl run demo-api-pod --image ***/demoapi:1.0.0.0 --env="ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80"
   ```

Thanks..